# hid.dll: Can hidd_getfeature() block?

Tags: c, windows, hid

Is there any way to make `hidd_getfeature()` block? Right now it returns immediately with `false`. This means I can only either busy-wait by looping until `hidd_getfeature()` returns `true`, or using some sort of other synchronization mechanism like an interrupt channel on the side.

What I would like is it to behave more like a socket or similar so it returns when a report is available.

Comment: this function present in many different APIs. Which one you are referring to ?

Comment: Title updated, it is Windows hid.dll api